# Find all integers $x,y,n,m$ such that $\gcd (n,m)=1$ and $(x^2+y^2)^n=(xy)^m$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all integers $x,y,n,m$, such that $\gcd (n,m)=1$ and $\left(x^2+y^2\right)^n=(xy)^m$.

When $(x,y)=(0,0)$, there are infinitely many solutions, so let's ignore that case.
I am able to show that $x,y$ must both be even for the equation to has a solution.
After some trail and error, I think that when $x,y$ are both even, and $x\neq y$, then $(x^2+y^2)$ must have an odd factor, and that means there is no solution for the equation. The problem then becomes to prove that $(x^2+y^2)$ must have an odd factor when $x,y$ are both even, but I am not entirely sure if that's right or how to prove it. Am I on the right track? Any idea on how to solve the problem?

**Edit:** When $x,y$ are both even and $x=y$, we have $(2x^2)^n=x^{2m}\implies 2^n=x^{2(m-n)}$, meaning that $n$ must be even since $x$ is even, and since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m$ must be odd. Suppose $n=2r, r\in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $2$ is the only factor of $x^{2(m-n)}$, then $x$ must be of the form $2^w,w\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, we have $2r=2w(m-2r)\implies m=r/w+2r$. We know that $m$ is odd, so $r=pw$, where $p$ is an odd integer. So the we have the solution $(x,y,m,n)=(2^w,2^w,2pw,p+pw)$, $p$ is odd, but then it is not for sure that $2pw,p+pw$ are coprime, so I am not sure how to express the solution in general variables.

Comment: I think you have made progress, but there are solutions when $x,y$ are even and equal.

Comment: Agree, I think n has to be even and m must be odd in that case.

Comment: This is question A3 from the 1992 Putnam competition. Please cite sources when you can!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: Thanks a lot, actually my professor gave me this problem, so I didn't know where the question is from, but thanks again for pointing me to the source. I will go check out the solution.